# Problem setting up DVWA in Wheezy 64 bits

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, php

I'm trying to get running Damn Vulnerable Web Application in a virtual machine with Wheezy. The easy way if it was 32 bits is install XAMPP and copy the dvwa to htdocs. However I'm using 64 bits and I don't want to be messing with 32 bits libs.

I've installed every needed component separately. I installed php5, mysql and apache2. Then I copied dvwa to /var/www/ but when I try to access it (127.0.0.1/dvwa/login.php) I get always a blank page.

I have never configured a web server so maybe I'm skipping something. I installed dvwa with xampp in a W7, and all was fine, so seems it's a misconfiguration in apache or something.

Comment: What does the apache error log say?

Comment: There is no error,  just blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had same issue. After some troubleshooting I found out that I don't have php5-mysql installed. So to fix this issue just install php5-mysql

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

and restart web service